# Struts unhandled exception - No result defined for action - Struts Spring & hibernate Integration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, struts2

Actually I'm working on implementing Struts Spring & Hibernate Integration on online Exam project. But While I'm submitting the values in the JSP page, it throws me the following error:

**Struts Problem Report**

```
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages:   
No result defined for action onlineexam.action.RegistrationAction and result 
success
```

**Stacktraces**

```
No result defined for action onlineexam.action.RegistrationAction and result success
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:363)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:265)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:251)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I have attached the RegistrationAction.java as follows

**RegistrationAction.java**

```
public class RegistrationAction extends ActionSupport {

    private UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService;

    public UserRegistrationService getUserRegistrationService() {
        return userRegistrationService;
    }

    public void setUserRegistrationService(
            UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService) {
        this.userRegistrationService = userRegistrationService;
    }

    private String first_Name;
    private String last_Name;
    private String emailid;
    private String passWord;
    private String Gender;
    private int dateofbirth;
    private int phoneNo;
    private float user_experience;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=UserDetails.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private int user_id;
    private String addr_line1;
    private String addr_line2;
    private String addr_line3;
    private String city;
    private int zipcode;
    private String state;
    private String country;

    public RegistrationAction() {
    }

// generated getters and setters

    public String SaveUserDetails() {
        String forward = "SUCCESS";

        try {
            UserDetails s = new UserDetails();
            s.setFirst_name(getFirst_Name());
            s.setLast_name(getLast_Name());
            s.setEmail(getEmailid());
            s.setPassword(getPassWord());
            s.setGender(getGender());
            s.setDob(getDateofbirth());
            s.setPhone(getPhoneNo());
            s.setExperience(getUser_experience());

            Set<UserAddress> address = new HashSet<UserAddress>(0);
            setUserAddress(address);
            userRegistrationService.saveUserRegistration(s);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            forward = "ERROR";
        }
        return forward;   }

    protected void setUserAddress(Set<UserAddress> address) throws Exception {
           UserAddress ad = new UserAddress();
           ad.setAddr_line1(getAddr_line1());
           ad.setAddr_line2(getAddr_line2());
           ad.setAddr_line3(getAddr_line3());
           ad.setCity(getCity());
           ad.setZipcode(getZipcode());
           ad.setState(getState());
           ad.setCountry(getCountry());

           address.add(ad); }
}
```

**MainLayout.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="tiles-jsp.tld" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="struts-tags.tld" prefix="struts"%>
<html>
<head>
  <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>ISAS:<tiles:insertAttribute name="title"/></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" ignore="true"/>

    <!-- Page Header -->
<div class="noprint">
    <table>
      <tr valign="top">
        <td width=10px></td>
        <td vAlign=top width="99%">         

                <div>
                     <span><tiles:insertAttribute name="pageHeading"/></span>
                </div>
         </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>  
    <!-- Navigation -->
<div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td vAlign=top align="center" width="100%"> 
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="nav" ignore="true"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>    
</div>

    <!-- Body Content -->
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>              
        <td width=10px></td>
        <td vAlign=top align="center" width="99%">  
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" ignore="true"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td vAlign=top align="center" width="99%">  
            <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" ignore="true"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where the problem is. While running this, it doesn't inserting the values in the mysql DB... I'm very new to this topic...Please Help me Friends... Anyway thanks in Advance friends...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong: `String forward = "SUCCESS";`

The right String is **"success"**;

```
String forward = "success";
```

and, since you are extending ActionSupport, you can use the constant SUCCESS to prevent future syntax errors.

```
String forward = SUCCESS;
```

The same mapping has to exist in Struts.xml. If you put "SUCCESS" in Struts.xml, go and change it, to prevent future headaches...

P.S: Same for "ERROR" that should be "error".

Comment: Thanks sir. i think its working but it throws me a different error right now.

Comment: Struts has detected an unhandled exception: 

Messages: /templates/MainLayout.jsp (line: 7, column: 14) The TLD for the class org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag specifies an invalid body-content (JSP) for a SimpleTag. 
ServletException including path '/templates/MainLayout.jsp'. 
ServletException including path '/templates/MainLayout.jsp'. 
 
File: org/apache/jasper/compiler/DefaultErrorHandler.java 
Line number: 42

Comment: I have uploaded the mainlayout.jsp file in this question sir. please have a look into it sir

Comment: it is showing error in the following line in mainlayout.jsp    <title>ISAS:<tiles:insertAttribute name="title"/></title>

Comment: Glad that helped (you can upvote too now, if you want :). For the other problem, it is a complete different question, so I advice you to open a new question on SO with different title and description; otherwise it would be difficult for future users to understand which problems are involved

Comment: Ok sir. I have posted a new question on the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767604/struts-has-detected-an-unhandled-exception-in-struts-spring-and-hibernate-integr